# Null Pointer Exception in If else case

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am using if else case on edit text field. In this if Edit text value is greater than 5 than popup will appear when I press submit button but when i not enter any value in edittext field than program will forcefully close and give error Null pointer Exception on if case.

My program is given below

```
   EditText name, temp,id_name;
Button submit,display;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
String resp=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nm);
    temp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.temp);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);


}


public void onClick(View butt)
{
    switch(butt.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            ds.setName(name.getText().toString());

            ds.setTemp(temp.getText().toString()); 

            if( temp > 5)
            {           
                tv1=new TextView(this);
                tv1.setText(" Temp is High");
                Dialog(tv1);
            }
            }

....
....
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which exit text you are talking about, where the else condition is and also please indent you code to make it more readable.

Comment: where is `difficulties1`and `preg` post relevant code

Comment: what is DS?? Please check Android beginner blogs for it.

Comment: in your own words........if the text in the `EditText` is `null` and you make a math calculation on this `null` value, as in `is null less than 5?`, you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It seems like you didnt paste all your code but without seeing the rest I guess that you forgot new TextView(...) inside the ELSE block

Comment: String s=name.getText().toString(); check if the edittext is null or not by using if(!s.isempty()).....then you check your condition

Comment: We could guess all night long, it is clear that you should post your LogCat errors and all of the relevant code if you want actual help.

Comment: kindly accept the answer if you have got yours..:)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Change your if with the following **code**

```
 if( temp.getText() != null && temp.getText().toString().length() > 5)
    {           
         tv1=new TextView(this);
         tv1.setText(" Temp is High");
         Dialog(tv1);
    }
```